# How To Run Multiple File Feature Automation Testing Using Behave On The Command Terminal

Tags: automated-tests, appium, appium-android, python-behave, python-appium

For an example, I have created some feature for automation testing using Behave `login_account.feature` and `choose_product.feature`. To run on a single feature, I use this command on the terminal `behave -f behave_html_formatter:HTMLFormatter -i login_account.feature`.

I want to run on multiple feature `login_account.feature` and `choose_product.feature` in one command on the terminal. Anyone, can you give me the example command to run multiple feature using Behave in one command on the terminal?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be two issues:

1. I'm not sure if that's the way to run with that formatter. See [behave-html-formatter docs](https://pypi.org/project/behave-html-formatter/) for config and example. I can't trial myself as I don't want/need this formatter installed. I would suggest you worry about this after you understand how to run multiple features, which is where issue #2 comes in.
2. `-i` expects a single argument, which is a regular expression pattern.
   Assuming you are in your `features` folder, just list the two features with space separator after the `behave` command:

`behave login_account.feature choose_product.feature`

Better still, you could use tags. This makes way more sense if you want to run more than the two files in your example. Add a tag at the top of each of the feature files you want to execute e.g. `@runme`.

Then execute only the ones having the preferred tag:

```
behave -t @runme
```